# How to integrate asyncronous python code into synchronous function?

Tags: python, async-await, python-requests, python-asyncio

I have an external library that uses `requests` module to perform http requests.
I need to use the library asynchronously without using many threads (it would be the last choice if nothing else works). And I can't change its source code either.
It would be easy to monkey-patch the library since all the interacting with `requests` module are done from a single function, but I don't know if I can monkey-patch synchronous function with asynchronous one (I mean async keyword).

Roughly, the problem simplifies to the following code:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import types
import requests


# Can't modify Library class.
class Library:
    def do(self):
        self._request('example.com')

        # Some other code here..

    def _request(self, url):
        return requests.get(url).text


# Monkey-patched to this method.
async def new_request(self, url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            return await response.text()


async def main():
    library = Library()

    # Do monkey-patch.
    library._request = types.MethodType(new_request, library)

    # Call library asynchronously in hope that it will perform requests using aiohttp.
    asyncio.gather(
        library.do(),
        library.do(),
        library.do()
    )

    print('Done.')

asyncio.run(main())
```

But as expected, it doesn't work. I get `TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required` on asyncio.gather call. And also `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'new_request' was never awaited` on `self._request('example.com')`.

So the question is: is it possible to make that code work without modifying the `Library` class' source code? Otherwise, what options do I have to make asynchronous requests using the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to make that code work without modifying the `Library` class' source code? Otherwise, what options do I have to make asynchronous requests using the library?

Yes, it is possible, and you even do not need monkey-patching to perform that. You should use [`asyncio.to_thread`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.to_thread) to make the synchronous `do` method of `Library` an asynchronous function ([coroutine](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines)). So the `main` coroutine should look like this:

```py
async def main():
    library = Library()

    await asyncio.gather(
        asyncio.to_thread(library.do),
        asyncio.to_thread(library.do),
        asyncio.to_thread(library.do)
    )

    print('Done.')
```

Here the `asyncio.to_thread` wraps the `library.do` method and returns a coroutine object avoiding the first error, but you also need `await` before `asyncio.gather`.

**NOTE**: If you are going to check my answer with the above example, please do not forget to set a valid URL instead of 'example.com'.

#### *Edit*

If you do not want to use threads at all, I would recommend an async wrapper like the `to_async` function below and replace `asyncio.to_thread` with that.

```py
async def to_async(func):
    return func()


async def main():
    library = Library()

    await asyncio.gather(
        to_async(library.do),
        to_async(library.do),
        to_async(library.do),
    )
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I wanted, because to_thread implies that it uses multithreading (uses ThreadPoolExecutor internally as default executor) instead of asynchronous asyncio loop. to_thread just lets you to await the result from a thread asynchronously. But it still executes in different threads. That's what I wanted to avoid if it's possible. But anyway, thank you for your answer. I didn't know about to_thread function and since my entire application uses asyncio I will use to_thread if I don't find a better solution.

Comment: @g00dds, I got your point and updated the answer. Please check the *Edit* section of my answer.

Comment: In this case the function seems never to be called at all. The whole source code file I ran to test this: https://pastebin.com/5pv3e59a. I even put a print in the `wrapper` function, it never gets called either.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it was initially implemented as a decorator, then I tried to use it as an ordinary function wrapper. Please check once again. This one is more simple.

Comment: I applied the changes. When monkey-patch is used, instead of the response `_request` function returns `coroutine` object so the further code fails with errors related to invalid response. Without the monkey-patch (just original function) code works, but synchronously, as if nothing was changed. The code(monkey-patching commented): https://pastebin.com/UveEi4Ws

Comment: My solution does not require a monkey patch. You should try without that.

Comment: As I said, I tried, but it works synchronously. Each request blocks the thread so the next request waits for the previous one to finish.

Answer (score 0):

I thought to release another answer as it solves the problem in another way.

So **why do not extend the default behavior of the `Library` class and make the `do` and `_request` methods polymorph?**

```py
class AsyncLibrary(Library):

    async def do(self):
        return await self._request('https://google.com/')

    async def _request(self, url):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                return await response.text()


async def main():
    library = AsyncLibrary()

    await asyncio.gather(
        library.do(),
        library.do(),
        library.do(),
    )
```

Comment: This is just like monkey-patching, but is done in another way. The other library's methods use overrided methods as synchronous. They do not await for the result, but instead use the returned value, which is `coroutine` for all async functions. This also means that I need to override all methods called until the `_request` call (`do` is not the first called method in the real library). The second problem is that the methods that use `_request` method do not consist of a single call to `_request`, but contains a lot of other logic and it would be hard to reimplement those methods.

Comment: I understand that the `do` is not the first called method in the real library and by changing its behavior can change others' behaviors too. I do not know what exact library you are using and my solution is based on your example. If you cannot or do not want change the original implementation of the `do` method, then you have to keep the `_request` method as a synchronous method because it is used in that way. In case you evaluate the `new_request` from overridden `_request` it will not make requests be sent asynchronous, and here the solution with `to_thread` became the best one. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

No way to do this with requests without threads but you can limit the number of threads active at any one time to address your *without using many threads* requirement.

```
import asyncio
import requests

# Can't modify Library class.
class Library:
    def do(self):
        self._request('http://example.com')
    def _request(self, url):
        return requests.get(url).text

async def as_thread(semaphore, func):
    async with semaphore:  # limit the number of threads active
        await asyncio.to_thread(func)

async def main():
    library = Library()
    semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(2)  # limit to 2 for example
    tasks = [library.do] * 10  # pretend there are a lot of sites to read
    await asyncio.gather(
        *[as_thread(semaphore, x) for x in tasks]
    )
    print('Done.')

asyncio.run(main())
```